# R graphics engine version 12 is not supported by this version of RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

Yesterday, I upgraded my version of R and today when I started a new session i got this :

```
R graphics engine version 12 is not supported by this version of RStudio. The Plots tab will be disabled until a newer version of RStudio is installed.
```

So when I tried to plot something like `x <- 1:10; plot(x, x^2)`, it opens a new window.

I use R 3.4.0 and Rstudio 1.0.44 and when I search updates for RStudio, it is said that I'm using the newest version.

Comment: Consider reverting your R version until further notice.

Comment: The current RStudio version [is 1.0.143](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200716783-RStudio-Release-History). Download and install the newest version.

Answer (score 0):

R Studio Server not compatible with newest version of R 3.4.0.

They is official information of R Studio - [link](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/211287987-R-graphics-engine-is-not-supported-by-old-version-of-RStudio-)

You can downgrade to R 3.2.5 or try preview release of R Studio Server v1.0.143 - [link](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/)