# Rstudio does not display graphics in plots panel

Tags: r, rstudio

After updating R, **Rstudio does not display graphics in plots panel** but in **"R Graphics: Device 2 (ACTIVE)"**.

Hereafter the R.version and RStudio.Version() that I suppose are the latest ones.

**R.version**

```
platform       i386-w64-mingw32            
arch           i386                        
os             mingw32                     
system         i386, mingw32               
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          4.0                         
year           2017                        
month          04                          
day            21                          
svn rev        72570                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
```

**RStudio.Version()**

```
$citation

To cite RStudio in publications use:

  RStudio Team (2015). RStudio: Integrated Development for R. RStudio, Inc.,
  Boston, MA URL http://www.rstudio.com/.

A BibTeX entry for LaTeX users is

  @Manual{,
    title = {RStudio: Integrated Development Environment for R},
    author = {{RStudio Team}},
    organization = {RStudio, Inc.},
    address = {Boston, MA},
    year = {2015},
    url = {http://www.rstudio.com/},
  }


$mode
[1] "desktop"

$version
[1] ‘0.99.902’
```

Comment: You need to download and install latest rstudio version. Also possible duplicate of:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38555768/unable-to-get-plots-displayed-in-rstudio-graphical-viewer

Comment: Thank you. In fact my version was not the latest one. After Installed it I don't have this problem anymore.

Comment: I thought my version was the latest one because when I checked for updates in the Help section I got  "You're using the newest version of RStudio".

Comment: Also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44064363/r-graphics-engine-version-12-is-not-supported-by-this-version-of-rstudio).